# Dynamically add titles to post images if they are empty

Tags: images, title

I have a client's site where they want to add image title attributes dynamically to images that don't have one already. So if the title attribute is empty, add a title of whatever the post title is. How would I accomplish this?

Effectively:
`<img src=img.jpg title=[wp-post-title-here] />`

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by "add" precisely? Adjust markup inserted into post content? Something else?

Comment: It is supposed to add the title attribute to an 'img' element @Rarst

Comment: @ZachRussell When should it do it? Should the title be added during saving given post or should it work also for old/existing posts?

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż It should work for old/existing posts and new posts.

Comment: How are you displaying the image on the page? `the_post_thumbnail`, `wp_get_attachment_image`, hard coding `<img src="<?php echo $src; ?>" />`, a gallery plugin, or some variant?

Comment: WordPress doesn't add `title` attributes to images so you would have to do this on the fly either with JQuery or `the_content` filter. The problem with this is that the only way you have access to the `attachment_id` via class `wp-image-123`. You could use this as [a start](http://www.paulund.co.uk/add-missing-alt-tags-to-wordpress-images) but I'm not sure how to create a clean solution.

Comment: May I step back for a moment and ask what's the point of that? The title should add information about the image, so I do not really see the usefulness of adding the post title. It is a good idea to add a title tag, but only if this information is useful and not just to tick off one more thing on a checklist.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following test plugin, that uses the [`domDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) class, to see how it works on your HTML.

It assumes PHP 5.4+ with LibXML 2.7.8+.

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Add Missing Image Title Attributes
 * Description: For posts in the main loop (Assumes PHP 5.4+ with LibXML 2.7.8+)
 * Plugin URI:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188560/26350
 * Author:      Birgir Erlendsson (birgire)
 * Version:     0.0.1
 */

namespace wpse\birgire;

add_action( 'init', function()
{
    $o = new AddMissingImgTitle;
    $o->activate( new \domDocument );
} );

class AddMissingImgTitle
{
    private $dom;

    public function activate( \domDocument $dom )
    {
        $this->dom = $dom;
        add_filter( 'the_content', [ $this, 'the_content' ] );
    }

    public function the_content( $html )
    {
        if( ! in_the_loop() )
            return $html;

        if( false === strpos( $html, '<img' ) )
            return $html;

        return $this->process( $html );
    }                                                               

    private function process( $html )
    {
        // Handle utf8 strings
        // See http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php#95251
        $html = '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $html;

        // Load without HTML wrapper
        // See https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/2078474
        $this->dom->loadHTML( $html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD );

        // Fetch all image tags:
        $images = $this->dom->getElementsByTagName( 'img' );
        foreach ( $images as $image )
        {
            // Add the title attribute if it's missing (using the post title):
            if( '' === $image->getAttribute( 'title' ) )
                $image->setAttribute( 'title', esc_attr( get_the_title() ) );
        }
        return str_replace( '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">', '', $this->dom->saveHTML() );
    }

} // end class
```

For older versions of LibXML, you can check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4879946/how-to-savehtml-of-domdocument-without-html-wrapper) for alternative ways without the `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED` and `LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` options.

Answer (score 1):

If we can assume that this is done properly for images that are in templates, and you're only concerned about page/post body content, you could use a filter when saving any post or page ( https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post ) to scan the content

> Since this action is triggered right after the post has been saved,
>   you can easily access this post object by using get_post($post_id)

You should then be able to do a search for all image tags `<img`, and if they do not have the phrase `title="` before the next `>`, insert right after `<img` your `title="post title here"`  - don't forget to re "save" the post after the whole function runs.

In order to do that, I would split the post string into substrings and then reassemble them again, but it's out of scope here to write all the code for you.

Alternatively you could do a similar scan for the image tags when the code is displayed to the page by filtering on get_content or similar, but it makes more sense to save into the database correctly, in regard to page load for viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Does the image title attribute actually have to be in the database? If it's only the matter of displaying text, for example in the photo gallery, would't using a jQuery function serve your purpose? Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('img').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('title') === undefined) {
         var title = $('h1').text();
         $(this).attr('title', title);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: I'm not looking for a jQuery solution. Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you want to load that image on post right... 
place the below code where you want images

```
<?php
$post_id = 75;
$thumbnail_id = 112;
if(!empty(get_the_title($thumbnail_id))){
    echo '<img src="img.jpg" title="'.get_the_title($thumbnail_id).'" />';
}
else{
    echo '<img src="img.jpg" title="'.get_the_title($post_id).'" />';
}

?>
```

i hope it will work for you...