# Disabling post images for not logged in users

Tags: plugins, functions, images

Is there any neat way of disabling the figures/images in a certain post category until a user logs in. I want the entire post content to be visible except for the images.

I'm not a programmer and I have not found any useful plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) and hook to [`the_content`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) filter by checking if user [is logged in](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_user_logged_in/).

add this to your `functions.php` file

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_remove_img' );
function wpse_remove_img( $content ){

  if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){

    // You need to specify which tag you want to keep here it's p, a, h2,span, div.
    // Adjust accordingly (you might want to add other or remove all)
    $content = strip_tags($content, '<p><a><h2><span><div>'); 


  }

  return $content;

}
```

**EDIT**

If you want to replace the image instead, I would use PHP [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to do the search and replace.

Note that some issues with text encoding can be experienced or warnings for some HTML5 tags. [Hakre](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11310258/4643867) explains in depth why this can happen and [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9149241) explains it well, both over at StackExchange.

In my solution below, I took care of that by defining the encoding before the `$content` is loaded.  And temporary disabling libxml errors so we don't get bugged with warnings by using [`libxml_use_internal_errors`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)

again, this goes into your `functions.php`

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_replace_img' );
function wpse_replace_img( $content ){

  if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){

    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // deactivating errors
    // Load without added HTML and doctype, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/4643867
    $dom->loadHTML( '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD ); // adding encoding
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false); // reactivating errors

    $tags = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'img' );

    foreach ($tags as $img) {
      $new_src_url = 'http://url/to/your/filler-image.jpg';
            $img->setAttribute( 'src', $new_src_url );
            $img->setAttribute( 'srcset', '' );

    }

    $content = $dom->saveHTML();

  }

  return $content;

}
```

**EDIT**

Ok, so here's an edit that takes into consideration wrapping `<a>` tags around images.
This first solution will replace the link to the image with a `#`

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_replace_img' );
function wpse_replace_img( $content ){

  if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){

    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    // Load without added HTML and doctype, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/4643867
    $dom->loadHTML( '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD ); // adding encoding
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

    $tags  = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'img' );

    foreach ($tags as $img) {
      $new_src_url = 'http://url/to/your/filler-image.jpg';
      $img->setAttribute( 'src', $new_src_url );
      $img->setAttribute( 'srcset', '' );

      if( $img->parentNode->tagName == 'a' ){ // if the current image is wrapped by an <a> tag, replace href link with an #

        $img->parentNode->setAttribute( 'href', '#' );

      }

    }

    $content = $dom->saveHTML();

  }

  return $content;

}
```

Then you could also remove the `<a>` tag altogether. With some help from [matb33](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10657666/4643867) over at stackoverflow I managed to come up with this solution.

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_replace_img' );
function wpse_replace_img( $content ){

  if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){

    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    // Load without added HTML and doctype, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/4643867
    $dom->loadHTML( '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD ); // adding encoding
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

    $tags  = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'img' );
    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();  // Create our new document fragment to manipulate


    foreach ($tags as $img) {
      $new_src_url = 'http://url/to/your/filler-image.jpg';
      $img->setAttribute( 'src', $new_src_url );
      $img->setAttribute( 'srcset', '' );

      if( $img->parentNode->tagName == 'a' ){ // if the current image has an  <a> tag as a parent apply replace our <a> tag with our <img> tag

        $a = $img->parentNode;
        $fragment->appendChild( $img->parentNode->childNodes->item( 0 ) ) ; // store our image node into the fragment
        $a->parentNode->replaceChild( $fragment, $a ); // replace our <a> tag with our <img> tag

      }

    }

    $content = $dom->saveHTML();

  }

  return $content;

}
```

**EDIT**

And here's how to apply only to specific categories

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'wpse_replace_img' );
function wpse_replace_img( $content ){

  if( ! is_user_logged_in() ){

    $apply_restriction = false;
    $categories = get_the_category();
    $restricted_cat = array(
        'restricted_cat_slug' // Our restricted category slug, since it's an array you could provide more than one
    );


    // Performing our check, switch the flag if we find a match
    foreach( $categories as $cat ){
        foreach( $restricted_cat as $r_cat ){
            if( $cat->slug == $r_cat ){
                $apply_restriction = true;
            }
        }
    }

    // Bail out without applying any restriction if no category match is found
    if( ! $apply_restriction ){
        return $content;
    }

    $dom = new DOMDocument();

    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
    // Load without added HTML and doctype, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/22490902/4643867
    $dom->loadHTML( '<?xml encoding="UTF-8">' . $content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD ); // adding encoding
    libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

    $tags  = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'img' );
    $fragment = $dom->createDocumentFragment();  // Create our new document fragment to manipulate


    foreach ($tags as $img) {
      $new_src_url = 'http://url/to/your/filler-image.jpg';
      $img->setAttribute( 'src', $new_src_url );
      $img->setAttribute( 'srcset', '' );

      if( $img->parentNode->tagName == 'a' ){ // if the current image has an  <a> tag as a parent apply replace our <a> tag with our <img> tag

        $a = $img->parentNode;
        $fragment->appendChild( $img->parentNode->childNodes->item( 0 ) ) ; // store our image node into the fragment
        $a->parentNode->replaceChild( $fragment, $a ); // replace our <a> tag with our <img> tag

      }

    }

    $content = $dom->saveHTML();

  }

  return $content;

}
```

Comment: Thats absolutely great! And thousand thanks for the prompt reply. Dare I ask what the corresponding tweak would be to replace all original images (in every post in a category) with one standard image (which will be a text saying: "log in to see this image") for all non logged in users? I would be immensely grateful.

Comment: @AdamRobinsson Edited my answer

Comment: Worked like a charm until i pressed the stand-in image, then the correct image (which was supposed to be blocked) appeared :-)
See for yourself: http://mitralis.se/uncategorized/test/

Comment: So the image with the bicycle is the _stand-in_ image and the image with the chair is the _blocked_ image?

Comment: exactly. I press the bicycle (stand-in) and up comes the image that should be blocked.

Comment: This is because when you inserted the image in your post, you chose to link the image to it's source file so the image is wrapped in an `<a>` tag. And the script I provided only checks for the actual image tag.  It doesn't remove the link wrapping that image. Do you want to have the link to the actual image or is this something you could turn off? If you need to keep this behaviour I would have to think of a way of also removing that link without affecting other links on the page

Comment: I noted the same issue for birgire's solution.

Comment: It works if I manually remove the link. For some strange reason it sets up a link automatically. Btw is there any easy way to apply this only to certain post categories?

Comment: ps: we should also remove the *doctype* and the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` tags as well, from the output of `$dom->saveHTML()`.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer and I managed to edit or remove the `<a>` tag programmatically, so if you ever need to use the link, it will be removed from non logged in users.  @birgire I don't see any `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` tags in the output of `$dom->saveHTML()`, are you sure they are automatically added? we are working with an incomplete HTML document so they are not there by default.

Comment: I noticed it first on the OP's test page and then I tested it on my install, and  I got that extra stuff too. I remember battling it [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/188560/26350), but I haven't revisited it since then. @bynicolas

Comment: @birgire you were right, I edited my answer to remove those extra tags from the source. Good call :)

Comment: @bynicolas FYI this doesn't work for images that have had --scaled or -scaled added by wordpress

Answer (score 2):

Here's a suggestion how to remove images, with *caption*, for visitors (not logged in):

```
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', function( $output, $attr, $content )
{
    $width = isset( $attr['width'] ) ? $attr['width'] : '300';
    $align = isset( $attr['align'] ) ? $attr['align'] : '';
    $class = isset( $attr['class'] ) ? $attr['class'] : 'no-image';

    $class = sprintf( 'wp-caption %s %s', $align, $class );

    return is_user_logged_in() 
        ? $output 
        : sprintf( 
            '<div class="%s" width="%d">%s</div>',
            esc_attr( $class ),
            (int) $width,
            esc_html__( 'Please log in to view the image', 'mydomain' )
        );
}, 10, 3 );
```

i.e. only images that are wrapped within the `[caption]` shortcode are replaced with a text.

The caption's *text* must be non-empty and the *width* non-zero.

Hope you can adjust it to your needs.

Here's an example:

[image: no-image]

Comment: Million thanks. Thats something I add to functions.php, right?

Comment: yes, that should work in `functions.php`, though it might be better to create a plugin, if you later decide to get a new theme and you still want this feature. @AdamRobinsson

Comment: this code turned out to have the same issue as above. It correctly displays the "stand-in" image (a bicycle) until you press the image, then the correct image, which should be blocked, turns out in a new window. http://mitralis.se/uncategorized/test/

Comment: I guess it's how you add the stand-in image - What's your current code snippet ? Did the stand-in text version work for you? I tested in on the default Twentysixteen theme. @AdamRobinsson

Comment: This also works beautifully. It did however, not replace the original image with a stand-in image. nevertheless it did the job. i'm grateful for your time.

Comment: You're welcome  PS: to use a stand-in image instead of a stand-in text, one can replace the sprintf part accordingly  @AdamRobinsson